# PSQLException trying to inject string in query Spring Boot JPA

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate

I would like to find all the records where a specific column (that is a timestamp), is greater than a specific timestamp... all of this using PostgreSQL.

I have the following repository:

```java
public interface IssuePublicationRepository extends IssueRepository {
    @Query(value = "SELECT * FROM issue WHERE created_at >= timestamp ?1", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Issue> findByMaxCreatedAt(String createdAt);
}
```

and I'm using it like this:

```java
issueRepository.findByMaxCreatedAt(
    new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.ITALY)
       .format(new Date(Instant.now().toEpochMilli() - 10L*30*24*60*60*1000)
    )
); // just a random date
```

however I'm getting:

```
2021-05-26 13:23:39.431 DEBUG 96462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : SELECT * FROM issue WHERE created_at >= timestamp ?
Hibernate: SELECT * FROM issue WHERE created_at >= timestamp ?
2021-05-26 13:23:39.432 TRACE 96462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [2020-07-30 13:23:39]
2021-05-26 13:23:39.438  WARN 96462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2021-05-26 13:23:39.438 ERROR 96462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
  Posizione: 51
2021-05-26 13:23:39.457 ERROR 96462 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet] with root cause

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1"
```

However, if i run

```
SELECT * FROM issue WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2020-07-30 13:21:41'
```

on my DBMS, it works fine

Comment: try to use `@Query(value = "SELECT i FROM issue i WHERE i.createdAt >= ?1")
    List<Issue> findByMaxCreatedAt(LocaleDateTime createdAt);`

Comment: I think you should quot it like `SELECT * FROM issue WHERE created_at >= timestamp '?1'`. Or better don't use `String` as param type and use `Timestamp` or `LocalDateTime`. So query would be `SELECT * FROM issue WHERE created_at >= ?1`

Comment: @YCF_L postgresql would copy the result in just one cell

Comment: @Alex I'll try that asap

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really must use a string, you will have to cast the parameter:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM issue WHERE created_at >= cast(?1 as timestamp)", nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: i'll try as soon as possible